# How to change node version in source tree or in husky?

Tags: node.js, npm, atlassian-sourcetree, husky

After I click **Push** in source tree, **husky** will run `npm test` and fail. I can find the message, 'husky > pre-push (node v17.9.0)'. So the node version is v17.9.0. I run unit test in my terminal which node version is v14.19.3 and succeed. How can I change the node version in my source tree or just change node version for husky? I use nvm to switch the node version, none of them is v17.9.0.

Comment: Do you get the same errors when you push without Sourcetree?

Comment: No, it work well in command line. And the node version in terminal is V14.19.3.

Answer (score 2):

Because I use nvm, and source tree doesn't import node version in nvm. So I input some code in **~/.huskyrc**.

```
# nvm
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

If you use zsh, just change some code

```
# nvm
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple versions of node for development and I got this error. I managed to fix it by deleting outdated/unused node versions in ~/.nvm/versions/node. I deleted v10.23.1 and v12.22.7 folders.

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

When attempting to commit, this forced Sourctree commit log included `Can't find node in PATH, trying to find a node binary on your system` indicating it fell back to the oldest version in the folder - v16.20.2

Answer (score -2):

you need to use this

```c
nvm use 14.19.3
```

note that you need to run this command as an administrator

Comment: How to run this command as an administrator in source tree ? It doesn't work when I add sudo.